# BAck to external browser closed app

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control, external

My application is opened in an external browser.

there possibility that when a person returns to the application will automatically close?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The browsers are all "sandboxes".  They can't detect when you return to your application.

The best you can do is in JavaScript, ask your window to close when you think the user is doing working in that tab (but the users can decline to close in some browsers):

```
function closeWin() {
     myWindow.close();   // Closes the new window
 }
```

Comment: I've added the code and put into the emulator and it worked. Thanks Baronz test and working perfect !!! followed all your advice and is working